# Importing SSL from Godaddy using Tomcat (SYSAID)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I've purchased an SSL cert from Godaddy and received the 3 following files:

4379ygfhd9745gh.crt
gd_bundle.crt
gd_intermediate.crt

http://www.sysaid.com/help-page.htm?helpPageId=4216&helpPageName=Home.htm&edition=2&version=v9.1.02&Admin=Y&productId=1&lang=en&notAddingIndexJSP=true

According to the Sysaid guide I was attempting to comply with, I need a ROOT Cert, a Intermediate Cert and the actual certificate in order to implement SSL in my server.

I have no idea which is which but I assumed gd_intermediate.crt was the Intermediate cert in question. So far all attempts to follow through Sysaid's guide failed when reaching:

keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore name.keystore -file certificate_filename

I get either

> "Public keys in reply and keystore dont match"
>
> or
>
> "Certificate reply does not contain public key for

I have no idea where to go from here...

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

I ended up taking the 2nd and surprisingly easy approach.

If you're looking to implement a authenticated SSL certificate with SYSAID,
I'd strongly suggest you generate a request on IIS, re-key it with your provider and eventually export it as pxf (pfx?). It is then a matter of 1 line to add in your Sysaid XML file and you are done.